# Next js file routing not working after deployment

Tags: github, next.js, deployment, vercel, next-link

i created and deployed a next js application on vercel using github , after deployment i access the site , i noticed that the homepage loads just fine but i am unable to access other pages the application returns **500 | internal server error**

these file routes (/Gal , /image/[slug] and /Shop ,/product/[slug]) which are created using "next/link" from nextjs  works just fine on localhost but does not work after deployment

[image]

[image]

Comment: Srajan, can you provide a screenshot of the file structure of your pages folder

Comment: yeah sure https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0evT.png